# Trouble mounting an EBS to a Pod in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

The cluster that I use is bootstrapped using kubeadm and it's deployed on AWS.

```
sudo kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.2", GitCommit:"17c77c7898218073f14c8d573582e8d2313dc740", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-24T06:51:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:”linux/amd64"}
```

I am trying to configure a pod to mount a persistent volume (I don’t think about PV and PVC for the moment), this is the manifest I used:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongodb-aws
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: mongodb-data
    awsElasticBlockStore:
      volumeID: vol-xxxxxx
      fsType: ext4
  containers:
  - image: mongo
    name: mongodb
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mongodb-data
      mountPath: /data/db
    ports:
    - containerPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
```

At first I had this error from the logs of the pod :

```
“ mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/vol-xxxx does not exist “
```

After some research, I discovered that I have to set a cloud provider and this is what I’ve tried to do for the 10 past hours, I tested many suggestions but none worked; I tried to tag all the resources used by the cluster as mentioned in: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53538#issuecomment-345942305, I also tried this official solution to run in-tree cloud providers with kubeadm : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/ :

*kubeadm_config.yml* file:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    cloud-provider: "aws"
    cloud-config: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
---
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kubernetesVersion: v1.12.0
apiServerExtraArgs:
  cloud-provider: "aws"
  cloud-config: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
apiServerExtraVolumes:
- name: cloud
  hostPath: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
  mountPath: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
controllerManagerExtraArgs:
  cloud-provider: "aws"
  cloud-config: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
controllerManagerExtraVolumes:
- name: cloud
  hostPath: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
  mountPath: “/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
```

In */etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf* I put :

```
[Global] 
KubernetesClusterTag=kubernetes
KubernetesClusterID=kubernetes
```

After running `kubeadm init --config kubeadm_config.yml` I had these errors:

```
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker.
Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
    - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster


The Control Plane is not created
```

When I removed :

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    cloud-provider: "aws"
    cloud-config: "/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf"
```

From kubeadm_config.yml and I run `kubeadm init --config kubeadm_config.yml`, the 
Kubernetes master had initialized successfully, but when I executed : `kubectl get pods —all-namespaces`, I got:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-ip-172-31-31-160                      1/1     Running            0          11m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-31-160            1/1     Running            0          11m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-31-160   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          11m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-31-160            1/1     Running            0          10m
```

The controller didn’t run.However the  --cloud-provider=aws command-line flag is present for the apiserver (in */etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml*) and also for the controller manager ( */etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml* )

When I run `sudo kubectl logs kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-13-85 -n kube-system` I got:

```
Flag --address has been deprecated, see --bind-address instead.
I1126 11:27:35.006433       1 serving.go:293] Generated self-signed cert (/var/run/kubernetes/kube-controller-manager.crt, /var/run/kubernetes/kube-controller-manager.key)
I1126 11:27:35.811493       1 controllermanager.go:143] Version: v1.12.0
I1126 11:27:35.812091       1 secure_serving.go:116] Serving securely on [::]:10257
I1126 11:27:35.812605       1 deprecated_insecure_serving.go:50] Serving insecurely on 127.0.0.1:10252
I1126 11:27:35.812760       1 leaderelection.go:187] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/kube-controller-manager...
I1126 11:27:53.260484       1 leaderelection.go:196] successfully acquired lease kube-system/kube-controller-manager
I1126 11:27:53.261474       1 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Endpoints", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-controller-manager", UID:"b0da1291-f16d-11e8-baeb-02a38a37cfd6", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"449", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'LeaderElection' ip-172-31-13-85_4603714e-f16e-11e8-8d9d-02a38a37cfd6 became leader
I1126 11:27:53.290493       1 aws.go:1042] Building AWS cloudprovider
I1126 11:27:53.290642       1 aws.go:1004] Zone not specified in configuration file; querying AWS metadata service
F1126 11:27:53.296760       1 controllermanager.go:192] error building controller context: cloud provider could not be initialized: could not init cloud provider "aws": error finding instance i-0b063e2a3c9797398: "error listing AWS instances: \"NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\\n\\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors\""
```

- I didn’t try to downgrade kubeadm (to be able to use manifests with only kind: MasterConfiguration)

If you need more information, please feel free to ask.

Comment: What is in the log for the controller manager pod that is in CLBO?

Comment: I added it to the post, I fixed "Zone not specified in configuration" by adding Zone=eu-west-1b to the file*/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf *, regarding the credentials, I don't need dynamic provisioning, I suppose I'm not forced to give the master the right to manage AWS resources (I cannot add them in Global anyway)

Comment: Well, then if you're not going to give the master the right to manage AWS resources, omit `--cloud-provider` entirely since that's everything that `--cloud-provider` would want to do: attach, detach (and optionally create) EBS volumes, update load balancers, perhaps subnets, discover instances, that kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I didn't know that the master needs permission to mount/unmount  EBS volumes, I thought it needs it just to create them, how can I do to give it the permissions (assign an IAM role to the instance where it runs is sufficient?)? and how can I configure Kubelet ?

Comment: Yes, the instance role is the normal way that is handled, and [here is an example policy](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/v2.7.0/contrib/aws_iam/kubernetes-master-policy.json). I don't have the time to dig up the documentation links for the cloud-provider options right now, but studying the [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/tree/v2.7.0) repo is a great way of seeing every single moving part without having to learn golang

Comment: I succeeded in mounting an EBS to a Pod running on the master (after tagging all the resources, giving all the permissions to the master and the worker and adding the flag --cloud-provider=aws to the master's Kubelet ), I'm trying to see how to add the flag --cloud-provider=aws to a worker's Kubelet so I can run the pod on the workers.